# Insert button after webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

Rather than inserting several content or script editor, is there another way to insert this line of code after a certain webpart? I have 3 web parts I want to have a button underneath them.

code to insert:
`<button class="btnBlue"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> View All Headlines</button>`

I was reading this page about [jquery .after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and tried below but it didn't work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// INSERT AFTER UPCOMING EVENTS WEBPART
    $( "#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" ).after( $( "<button class="btnBlue"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i> View All Events</button>") );
</script>
```

Also tried with `#WebPartWPQ2`.

**Edit**
This line worked `$( "#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2" ).after('<button class="btnBlue"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> View All Headlines</button>');`  but when I added another line for another webpart, it didnt work again `$( "#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5" ).after('<button class="btnBlue"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar"></i> View All Events</button>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `appendChild` as the following

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var div = document.createElement('div');   
      div.innerHTML = '<button class="btnBlue"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bars"></i> View All Headlines</button>';
      document.getElementById('WebPartWPQ2').appendChild(div);
  });
</script>
```

**[Output]**

[image]